# How can I run opencv through linux terminal

Tags: linux, opencv, terminal

Recently, I wrote a program using **opencv** that:

1. Opens the camera
2. Takes 150 pictures of a chessboard pattern, and
3. Plots all 150 points in a scatter plot

Each point represents the location of the bottom right corner of the chessboard relative to the camera.

However, I did all of this using **VS Code**, including running the program. I am currently using a **Linux** computer.

Is there a way for me to run this program using Linux terminal? If yes, how could I do this?

I don't really know what to try and I googled this but couldn't find any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

just open a terminal, and create a cpp file from it, like this:
"nano opencv-program1.cpp".

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
// Create a video capture object to capture video from the camera (0 for the default camera)
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

```
// Check if the camera opened successfully
if (!cap.isOpened()) {
    std::cerr << "Error opening the camera." << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

// Create a window to display the camera feed
cv::namedWindow("Camera", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);

while (true) {
    cv::Mat frame;

    // Capture a frame from the camera
    cap >> frame;

    // Display the frame in the window
    cv::imshow("Camera", frame);

    // Wait for 30 milliseconds and check if the 'q' key is pressed to exit
    if (cv::waitKey(30) == 'q') {
        break;
    }
}

// Release the camera and close the window when done
cap.release();
cv::destroyAllWindows();

return 0;
```

}

To save the file, just type ctrl + s, then ctrl + x to exit nano. Which is the text editor.
Then just compile it with the following command:

g++ -o camera_capture opencv-program1 `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`

Of course, your need to have opencv installed first. Use this commando to do so:

sudo apt install libopencv-dev -y